# Filter exact ID when comparing relationships

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter an ID when comparing two relationships, this is the code I have:

### Models:

***ModelA***

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.id)
```

***ModelB***

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    relationship = models.OneToOneField(ModelA)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.relationship)
```

***ModelC***

```
class ModelC(models.Model):
    relationship_A = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', null=True, blank=True)
    relationship_B = models.ForeignKey('ModelB', null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.id)
```

---

### Views:

***View of the ModelA***

```
def RegModelA(request):
        form = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ModelAForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                save = form.save()
                create_modelc = ModelC.objects.create(relationship_A=save, relationship_B=None)
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = ModelAForm()
        return render(request, "template.html", {"form":form})
```

The result so far is the following:

[Click to see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsTfs.png)

---

***View of the ModelB***

```
def RegModelB(request):
        form = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ModelBForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                save = form.save()
                update_modelc = ModelC.objects.filter().update(relationship_B=save)
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = ModelBForm()
        return render(request, "template.html", {"form":form})
```

I want to get the exact ID of the ModelC when `relationship_A == save_relationship` so that it is updated relationship_B.

How should I use the filter to get that id in the ModelB view?

---

**Using:** Python 3.5 & Django 1.11

Comment: what is `save_relationship` here according to you ?

Comment: It is the OneToOne relationship in the ModelB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to get one or multiple instance of `ModelC` based on `ModelA`s `id` property. Django let's you query properties spanning across relationships with the double underscore operator `__`, resulting in the following query:

```
ModelC.objects.filter(relationship_A__id=save.relationship.id)
# or
ModelC.objects.filter(relationship_A=save.relationship.id)
#
ModelC.objects.filter(relationship_a=save.relationship)
```

That said, note that this is a huge bug waiting to happen. As you are using `filter` on `ModelC`, you are querying the entire database, which may lead to unwanted behaviour. This is the case if you have multiple instances of `ModelC`, which have the same `ModelA` instance, while you'd only like to update the most recent one.